# Can I print two copies of a document on the same page but different sides?

Tags: windows, windows-8, pdf, printing

I have tried several things, but Windows always prints a different page for the second copy even if I select print two sided.
If I print more than onepage, Windows will print page 1 and 2 on one sheet and pages 1 and 2 again in the other sheet... even if I choose not to collate!
Is there a way to send a document and have the exact same thing be printed in both sides?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I haven't used Adobe reader for years, but Foxit reader ([www.foxitsoftware.com](http://www.foxitsoftware.com)) which I use has a print box similar to Office, where you can specify a page list, so you simply specify **1,1,2,2...**. That works perfectly with double-sided printing.

Foxit reader is freeware.

Answer (score 2):

Sure, but it's a kludge. Select everything on a page, copy, paste, paste, print.

Kludge 2 - print one sided, put output back in printer, print again.

(I'll take a kludge that works until something better comes along, sometimes longer if it's not a painful kludge)

Answer (score 0):

This might as well be an issue with your drivers. Update or reinstall them, your machine is either using a generic driver (hence why it can't use the two-sided printing feature correctly) or the one you already have is buggy.

Just to expand **Ecnerwal's** answer, you can try specifying the number of extra copies (1 in this case) while you have the two-sided printing enabled and by printing only the page you want to be copied (by specifying it manually). Something like this:

```
Number of copies = 1
Print two-sided = true
Print page = page number 1
```

And if this works, repeat the process for every other page.

Since I assume you're using Windows' built-in printing panel you may want to update your system, or Office if you're using it.

Comment: Yeah, I tried that, but it doesn't work. Interestingly enough, it will just print each page in a different sheet. If I have more than one page, it will interleave them.

Comment: So, it only prints 1 sheet only on 1 side? weird, have you tried updating or installing the drivers?